# iOS check if object can be retained

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a method with an id parameter in it. I also have an id as a property inside my class. My question is in the init method is there a way I can determine if the passed parameter can be retained so I can do something like:

```
someProperty = [idParameter retain];
```

Thanks

Comment: If it's an `id`, I can't think of a reason where you *can't* retain it.

Answer (score 3):

All Objective-C objects (i.e. anything inheriting from the `NSObject` class or implementing the `NSObject` protocol) implement `retain`.  It's implemented by the `NSObject` class and it's a required method for the protocol, so you cannot have an Objective-C object that you cannot call `retain` on.

The only time you'd not be able to call it in these circumstances is if your variable of type `id` was not pointing to an Objective-C object.  This would be a mistake, do not do this.

Answer (score 2):

Every object that inherits from NSObject has a `respondsToSelector:` method. ([Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html))

Therefore, you could write:

```
if ([idParameter respondsToSelector:@selector(retain)])
    someProperty = [idParameter retain];
```

Comment: There's no need for this.  `NSObject` implements `retain` and it's a required method for the `NSObject` protocol.  That conditional will always evaluate to `YES`.

Comment: Or to put @Jim's comment another way: How do you know `idParameter` responds to `-respondsToSelector:`?  If you just assume it, you might as well just assume the object responds to `-retain`  They are both declared in the `NSObject` protocol.